# laravel database seeding with one to many where counter needs to reset

Tags: database, laravel, one-to-many, seeding

I'm creating an api for a recipe app and I'm having trouble with generating seed data. The recipe database has 4 for tables: users, recipes, recipe_ingredients and recipe_steps.

User hasMany recipes.
Recipe belongs to User.
Recipe hasMany Ingredients (1 to n).
Recipe hasMany Steps (1 to n).

So far the seed generating code seems to work up to and including generating 5 to 10 ingredients randomly for each recipe. When generating data for the steps, the step_order keeps incrementing for each recipe but not the way I am expecting. I need the step_order to begin at 1 for each recipe.

I'm running this on a local ubuntu 18.04 desktop in development using the built-in php server.

Here is what I have for the table migrations:

**create_recipes_table:**

```
if (!Schema::hasTable('recipes')) {
   Schema::create('recipes', static function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->bigIncrements('id');
     $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
     $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
     $table->string('title', 256);
     $table->longText('description');
     $table->timestamps();
   });
}
```

**create_recipe_ingredients_table:**

```
if (!Schema::hasTable('recipe_ingredients')) {
   Schema::create('recipe_ingredients', static function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->unsignedBigInteger('recipe_id');
     $table->string('name', 100);
     $table->string('quantity', '15');
     $table->timestamps();
     $table->foreign('recipe_id')->references('id')->on('recipes')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

**create_recipe_steps_table:**

```
if (!Schema::hasTable('recipe_steps')) {
   Schema::create('recipe_steps', static function (Blueprint $table){
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('recipe_id');
      $table->unsignedInteger('step_order');
      $table->text('description');
      $table->timestamps();
      $table->foreign('recipe_id')->references('id')->on('recipes')->onDelete('cascade');
   });
}
```

**Recipe model:**

```
public function User(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    {
        /** @var Recipe $this */
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function ingredients(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Ingredient::class);
    }

    public function steps(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Ingredient::class);
    }
```

**Ingredient model:**

```
public function Recipe(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
{
    /** @var Ingredient $this */
    return $this->belongsTo(Recipe::class);
}
```

**Step model:**

```
public function Recipe(): BelongsTo
{
     /** @var Ingredient $this */
     return $this->belongsTo(Recipe::class);
}
```

**RecipeFactory:**

```
$factory->define(Recipe::class, static function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => factory(User::class)->create()->id,
        'title' => rtrim($faker->sentence(random_int(5, 10)), '.'),
        'description' => $faker->paragraphs(random_int(3, 7), true),
    ];
});
```

**RecipeIngredientsFactory:**

```
$factory->define(Ingredient::class, static function (Faker $faker) {
    $quantityTypeAmount = $faker->randomFloat(2, 0, 10);
    $quantityTypeString = $faker->randomElements(
        ['tsp.', 'tbsp.', 'fl oz.', 'gill.', 'cup.', 'pt.', 'qt.', 'gal.', 'ml.', 'L', 'dl',]
    );
    return [
        'name' => $faker->words(random_int(3, 7), true),
        'quantity' => (string)$quantityTypeAmount . ' ' . $quantityTypeString[0]
    ];
});
```

**RecipeStepsFactory:**

```
$factory->define(Step::class, static function (Faker $faker) {
    static $step_order = 1;
    return [
        'step_order' => $step_order++,
        'description' => $faker->sentences(random_int(1, 4), true),
    ];
});
```

**DatabaseSeeder:**

```
// Create 5 users.
factory(User::class, 5)->create()->each(static function (User $user) {
    // Create 5 - 10 recipes for each user.
    factory(Recipe::class, 5)->create(['user_id'=>$user->id])->each(static function (Recipe $recipe) {

        // For each recipe, create 5 - 10 ingredients randomly.
        $recipe->ingredients()->saveMany(factory(Ingredient::class, random_int(3,7))->make());

        // For each recipe, create 1 - 5 steps for each recipe
        $recipe->steps()->saveMany(factory(Step::class,random_int(1,5))->make());

    });
});
```

I'm not getting any error messages.

I'm expecting the step_order in the recipe_steps table to increment from 1 to n for each recipe. However, currently the step_order continues to increment for each recipe.

For instance, currently, I am getting:

```
recipe_id - step_order - description 
    1            1         -------
    1            2         -------
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
    1            10        -------
    2            11        -------
    2            12        -------
etc...
```

What I am expecting:

```
recipe_id - step_order - description 
    1            1         -------
    1            2         -------
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
    1            10        -------
    2            1         -------
    2            2         -------
    2            3         -------
    3            1         -------
    3            2         -------   
etc...
```

I'm thinking I need some sort of intermediate table. The other term I have read associated with this is a pivot table. The only thing I'm familiar with is the intermediate table but I don't know how to implement one in Laravel, if that is what I need.

Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd remove second line from RecipeStepsFactory and give 'step_order' default value of 1

```
$factory->define(Step::class, static function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'step_order' => 1, // default value of 1
        'description' => $faker->sentences(random_int(1, 4), true),
    ];
});
```

then in the DatabaseSeeder file I would execute the recipe seeder as follows

```
$steps = random_int(1,5);

// For each recipe, create 1 - 5 steps for each recipe
for ($i = 1; $i <= $steps; $i++) {
   $recipe->steps()->save(factory(Step::class)->make(['step_order' => $i]));
}
```

Comment: That works.  :)   Thank you!  I had to set the for loop initializer to 1 otherwise it starts at 0.